# OpenCV capturing video Ubuntu 12.0.4

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu

I need some help with a weird problem for me.

I did a simple application for capturing video in Ubuntu 12.0.4 I am using eclipse and OpenCV libraries with C++. So the problem is that I was working with a kind of IPcameras and everything was going perfect, here is the code which I was working:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cv::VideoCapture cap("http//:192.168.1.11:80/videostream.cgi?resolution=320x240&rate=0&user=admin&pwd=admin&.mjpg");

    cv::Mat frame;
    cv::namedWindow("video");

    cvMoveWindow("video", 0, 0);

    while ( cap.isOpened() )
    {       
        cap >> frame;

        if(frame.empty()) break;

        cv::imshow("video", frame);

        if(cv::waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

That works very nice. My problem is that now I have to work with other IPcameras, and I have no idea why it does not work, I am using the same code (changing the Ip) and nothing the application is just as thinking. The thing is I can see the camera through browser, so the camera is working, then I thought that should be code problem the capturing structure but I tried many combination and nothing, I check the IPcamera documentation and there is nothing.

Comment: May be the camera is busy, or opened in other application. I don't know about IP cameras, but for webcams, openCV requires exclusive lock of the device.

Comment: Now I got to see the camera on the browser changing the resolution, so I tap: resolution=32 instead of resolution=320x240 And it is working on the browser so the problem look like a resolution problem I guess that the camera is not busy, but I still can not see the camera from my application, look like for some reason the application can not capture the video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find out the solution, finally the problem was that the IP cameras which I am using use a "rtsp" protocol however I was trying to use http.

I had to use "rtsp"

Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your IP adress is not well formatted  (use `http://` instead of `http//:`)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cv::VideoCapture cap("http://192.168.1.11:80/videostream.cgi?resolution=320x240&rate=0&user=admin&pwd=admin&.mjpg");
    cv::Mat frame;
    cv::namedWindow("video");

    ...
}
```

`:` must follow immediately the protocol name ( http )

Comment: Hi Marcassin sorry about that it was a copy & paste error, I have the propertly format http:// sorry

Comment: Sorry for you because you're problem isn't solved :-)

Answer (score -1):

Try following code to capture....

```
if(cap.isOpened())
{
while ( cap.grab() )
    {       
        cap.retrieve(frame);

        cv::imshow("video", frame);

        if(cv::waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer I tried your code but is the same, I think that the problem is in the capture because If I write cout<<"Ready"<<endl; for example after cv::VideoCapture cap; I can not see anything through the console so the program does not pass the cap

Comment: cv::VideoCapture cap;
const std::string videoStreamAddress = "http://192.168.1.47/videostream.cgi?user=admin&pwd=admin&rate=0&resolution=32&.mjpg";

if(!cap.open(videoStreamAddress)) {
std::cout << "Error opening video stream or file" << std::endl;
         return -1;
     }

Comment: And even it does not show me anything, nothing about "error opening video...." so It can not even open the video. I do not what more I can do